# reloadRowsAtIndexPaths reloading two adjacent rows

Tags: ios, uitableview, reloaddata

I am reloading my `UITableViewCell` using `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`. But it is calling reload data of more than one row.

Code to reload a single cell on a button (inside `UITableViewCell`):

```
NSIndexPath *currentIndex = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:self];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[currentIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Does `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` trigger two reloads as I am getting?

Comment: Apart from currentIndex which other rows are getting reloaded?

Comment: The very next row. I guess they are reloading all visible rows.

Comment: Code looks ok, you have other issue somewhere, I guess.

Comment: When I set reloadData it is working fine. But when I am using reloadRowsAtIndexPaths, it gives me wrong view orientation. My cell contains video playback view. This view is removed from super view. Changing reloadData to reloadRowsAtIndexPaths is the only change I made.